# check if the first list is a sublist of the second one python

Tags: python

I started study python and I arrive at list and recursion. I saw an exercise. It says Write a function that takes two lists as parameters and checks whether the first is a sublist of the second. Note that the elements in the lists may be lists themselves. At the beginning I thought it was easy but then I saw that the tricky thing is that my function has to accept nested lists (like [1,2,[3,[4,5]]]) and has to be in recursion. I know how to do it with recursion and with normal lists. I have no idea of how to apply the recursion to the nested lists. Can you help me?

```
el1 = ''
el2 = ''
list1 = []
list2 = []
while el1 != "exit":
    el1 = input("Insert the words of the first list: ")
    print("write exit to finish")
    list1.append(el1)
while el2 != "exit":
    el2 = input("Insert the words of the second list: ")
    print("write exit to finish")
    list2.append(el2)
for x in list2:
    if x not in list1:
        print("FALSE")
        break
    else:
        print("TRUE")
        break
```

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of of "sublist" in this context? Is `[1,3]` a sublist of `[1,2,3]`? Is `[1, 2]` a sublist of `[[1],[2]]`?

Comment: Well, it's a text of an exercise. As I understand (and as you understand as well) I right you are right. The list [1,3] is a sublist of [1,2,3]. I don't thing the second one is right (Maybe it is in discrete mathematics :D )

Comment: I don't think you need a recursive function to check if one list is a sublist of another.  Just compare the values of the list elements.  Recursive or not, that should work.  Or you can use sets in Python.  One other question - is [3,1] a sublist of [1,2,3]?

Comment: yes yes. As I wrote, I'm perfectly able to do it without recursion but then in the book I saw that there is a part of the exercise that asks for the same function with the recursion. How can I solve it with recursion? My problem, as I said, is to "iterate" through the nested list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it, try to substruct the items of first list from the second one. If the length changes, it means that the items of the first list are in the second one too, else: True.

To clarify the idea, check this quick example:

```
l1= ['alpha','beta']
l2= ['alpha','beta','gama','theta']
l3= ['AnotherWord']

print len(list(set(l2)-set(l1)))==len(l2) #Case where l1 is a sublist of l2
print len(list(set(l2)-set(l3)))==len(l2) #case where l3 is not a sublist of l2
```

SO your code would look like:

```
el1 = ''
el2 = ''
list1 = []
list2 = []
while el1 != "exit":
    el1 = input("Insert the words of the first list: ")
    print("write exit to finish")
    list1.append(el1)
while el2 != "exit":
    el2 = input("Insert the words of the second list: ")
    print("write exit to finish")
    list2.append(el2)

if len(list(set(list2)-set(list1)))==len(list2): 
    print("List 1 is a sublist of List 2")
else: 
    print("List 1 is not a sublist of List 2")
```

**UPDATE**

```
a,b= [1,2,[3,[4,5]]], [4,5]

c,d= [1,2,[3,[4,5]]], [3,4,5]
def isSublist(a,b): 
    return any(x if x==b else isSublist(x,b) for x in a if isinstance(x,list) )

print isSublist(a,b) #True
print isSublist(c,d) #False
```

Comment: The question is about nested lists and recursion.

Comment: it's basically what I did but the problem, as I said, is that I don't know how to do it with recursion

Comment: ah Thanks @Roman. But it's a little bit ambiguous as he can't add list of list in the code he provided. Going to modify the code

Comment: @pp94 In addition to Roman's answer, Check **Update**, I tried to write a recursive function + using any operator.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would understand this exercise is that [1,3] is *not* a sublist of [1,2,3], but rather [2,3] is a sublist of [1,[2,3]]. In this case, a list A is a sublist of B if there exists an element `el` in B such that `el == A`. In order to find this `el` you need to traverse B recursively, and here is a skeleton for your code so that you can figure out the rest and complete the exercise:

```
def is_sublist(x,y):
  for item in x:
    # some comparison and control flow
    if isinstance(item, list):
      # some code recursively calling is_sublist and more control flow
```

And here are a few tests for the final code:

```
print is_sublist([1,2,[3,[4,5]]], [4,5])     # True
print is_sublist([1,2,[3,[4,5]]], [3,[4,5]]) # True
print is_sublist([1,2,[3,[4,5]]], [3,4,5])   # False
```